# processing js .pde referenced in canvas not working on Firefox & IE

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, canvas, processing

I have the following working in Safari & Chrome on a Mac. I just switched over to check Firefox Mac and IE on PC and it's not working. I can't seem to figure out why! Any suggestions would be grand.

http://davidcool.com/experiments/follow.html

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>follow</title>
    <script src=processing-1.4.1.min.js></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:50;">
        <canvas data-processing-sources="harmonograph_v2_1_logo.pde" tabindex="0" id="__processing0" width="1300" height="160"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As per Mike's suggestions, I stripped this down to bare bones and it still doesn't work in PC IE or Mac Firefox. Chrome and Safari Mac work fine. I added in the encoding as firebug was giving me an error. No effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test pjs</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
<script src="processing-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <canvas data-processing-sources="harmonograph.pjs"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also built a converter and converted the sketch from processing .pde file to processing js .pjs format here: http://generactive.net/tools/pde_to_pjs/convert_to_pjs.html?#

The converted files work fine in the same two browsers as well.

Okay, an update on this problem. I've since replaced the sketch and it now works. So the problem is in the sketch somewhere. I'm not sure what the problem is, or why it works on some brewers and not others, but something in the sketch kills certain browsers. The code above should work fine.

Comment: What meant to happen? I just see a black strip on both Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Please tell us what the expected behavior is. I see the black strip with a drawing animation.

Comment: It should look like a variation of this: http://davidcool.com/experiments/harmonograph.png If you view this page on Mac Safari or Chrome it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

the Pjs library has special characters in its name, so it requires quoting: `<script src="processing-1.4.1.min.js"></script>`. It's good practice to just quote your attribute strings, since only continuous non-special-character strings can be left unquoted.

On a secondary note, you don't really need the `tabindex="0" id="__processing0"` bits, those are automatically added by Pjs (if you're using a self-specified id attribute, better to give it a real name instead).

Finally, `<div style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:50;">` won't do very much, height wise, unless you specified CSS rules for html and body that set them up as heigth 100%, too. Basically, certainly to first get things working, I'd recommend not specifying width and height in both the canvas, and the container. Let the div figure out the dimensions it needs to autofit to, and let the canvas get its size from your `size(...,...)` call inside your `setup` function in the pde file.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried some of those already to no avail. It works fine on Safari and Chrome on Mac. I've since converted the .pde file to a .pjs file with a converter I built here: http://generactive.net/tools/pde_to_pjs/convert_to_pjs.html?# The converted files are working great on Mac Safari and Chrome as well. My most recent code is edited above in the original post.